# React setState not working on first try, but works on second?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have the `handleSelection` method called when a button is clicked, however, if I click the button once the state does not get set when it gets to `this.setState({selectedFoods: newSelections});`. Everything else in the method executes correctly (as my various console.logs tell me :) ). When the button is clicked a second time, everything in the method gets executed again and the `setState` works.

```
var Flavor = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { foods: {}, selectedFoods: [], affinities: [] };
  },
        componentDidMount: function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: this.props.url,
              dataType: 'json',
              cache: false,
              success: function(data) {
                this.setState({foods: data});
              }.bind(this),
              error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
              }.bind(this)
            });
          },
  componentDidUpdate: function () {
    $('#select-food').selectize({
      onChange: this.handleSelection
      }
    );
  },
  handleSelection: function (e) {
    if (e.target) {
      var selectedFood = e.target.id;
    } else {
      var selectedFood = e;
    }
    console.log(selectedFood);

    if (this.state.foods[selectedFood]) {
      var selections = this.state.selectedFoods;
      var newSelections = selections.concat(selectedFood);
      console.log("newSelections: "+newSelections)
      var state = Object.assign(this.state, {selectedFoods: newSelections});
      this.setState(state);
      console.log("state: "+this.state.selectedFoods)
      this.handleAffinities();
    } else {
      console.log("** "+selectedFood+" **");
    }

  },
  handleAffinities: function() {

    console.log("selectedFoods: "+this.state.selectedFoods.length)
    if (this.state.selectedFoods.length > 0) {
      var allAffinities = this.state.selectedFoods.map((food) => {
        return this.state.foods[food];
      });
      console.log(allAffinities.length);
      console.log(allAffinities);

      var commonAffinities = allAffinities[0];

      allAffinities.forEach((affinities) => {
        commonAffinities = commonAffinities.filter((n) => {
          return affinities.indexOf(n) != -1;
        });
      })

      this.setState({affinities: commonAffinities});
    } else {
      this.setState({ affinities: [] });
    }

  },
  handleRemove: function(food) {
    var selectedFoods = this.state.selectedFoods;
    var index = selectedFoods.indexOf(food);
    var updatedSelection = selectedFoods.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({selectedFoods: selectedFoods});
    this.handleAffinities();
  },
```

Why does everything execute correctly the first time except my `setState` function? And why it work on the second click?

Comment: Any chances that your `if (this.state.foods[selectedFood])` is not valid for some reason ? maybe `this.state.foods` is still empty the first time or something like that ?

Comment: What's in your `getInitialState` function? Can you post the entire component, perhaps in a JSFiddle?

Comment: thanks, i added everything up to the render method

Comment: @MouhamedHalloul it is passing the conditional b/c the other code inside it executes

Comment: I was able to get it to work by replacing it with this: 
`var state = Object.assign(this.state, {selectedFoods: newSelections});
this.setState(state);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 47):

The state is changing exactly the way it is supposed to.  The problem is that your `console.log` statements immediately after your call to `setState` are firing before the new state is set.

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html):

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

If you'd like to fire a `console.log` statement after the state transition completes, pass a function as a callback to `setState()`.

```
this.setState({selectedFoods: newSelections}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.selectedFoods);
});
```

Comment: this is really good to know. my component's state isn't getting updated also by evidence of the DOM not changing as intended though.

Comment: Just to note: I was struggling with a toggling function in which I needed something like this: "Immediately after this.setState i needed a function to trigger. I solved it by passing that function call within the setState callback as @Michael said and it worked fantastically.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was having a headache of a time trying to figure this out. Now all of my setState uses a callback and I have no issues.

Comment: Excelent answer. it helped my code; Now I can make a request as soon the setState has been set. :)

Comment: Thanks alot for this.

Answer (score 2):

As @Micheal stated, setState function stays pending, and first console.log works. Anybody who wants to see or experiment this situation, may have a look at my [codesandbox.io example](https://codesandbox.io/s/class-vs-functional-component-basic-example-m82ui?file=/src/YesNoComponentWithClass.js). Here, inside YesNoComponentWithClass, yes button logs empty for the first click, while no button logs the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered from this problem for a day and got the solution.
I just added in myCode  the componentDidUpdate() method , and now everything working well.
For the flow of the life cycle check out the life cycle image given in link.

Answer (score 0):

In my problem I was making an API request and then setting the state with the returned values. I did not want the page to re-render so my state values where  batching when updated and updated after 2-3 tries.

I fixed it when I noticed my post request was executing (sending data) during OPTIONS and then my GET request would retrieve data, then my POST would fulfill. If someone experiences the problem with API calls and reloading the page to update state is not an option maybe this will help.

```
setData(newEquipment).then(() => {
            grabData(nS).then(json => {
                if (json["cs"]) {
                    json["cs"].map((item: CMs) => {
                        if (item.label === "SE") {
                            item.metrics.map((mes: Ms) => {
                                if (mes.label === "1") {
                                    const a = mes.value;
                                    setSEs(a);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    )
                }
            });
        });
```