# setState doesn't update the state immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I would like to ask why my state is not changing when I do an `onClick` event. I've search a while ago that I need to bind the `onClick` function in constructor but still the state is not updating.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Col';
import BoardAddModal from 'components/board/BoardAddModal.jsx';    
import style from 'styles/boarditem.css';

class BoardAdd extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);    
        this.state = {
            boardAddModalShow: false
        };    
        this.openAddBoardModal = this.openAddBoardModal.bind(this);
    }

    openAddBoardModal() {
        this.setState({ boardAddModalShow: true }); // set boardAddModalShow to true

        /* After setting a new state it still returns a false value */
        console.log(this.state.boardAddModalShow);   
    }

    render() {    
        return (
            <Col lg={3}>
                <a href="javascript:;" 
                   className={style.boardItemAdd} 
                   onClick={this.openAddBoardModal}>
                    <div className={[style.boardItemContainer,
                                     style.boardItemGray].join(' ')}>
                        Create New Board
                    </div>
                </a>
            </Col>
        );
    }
}

export default BoardAdd
```

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225502/157247) you've accepted on this question makes no sense. `setState` doesn't return a promise. If it worked, it only worked because `await` introduces one async "tick" into the function, and it **happened** that the state update got processed during that tick. It's not guaranteed. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41278440/157247) says, you need to use the completion callback (if you really need to do something after the state is updated, which is unusual; normally, you just want to re-render, which hapens automatically).

Comment: It would be good if you un-accepted the currently accepteded answer or accepted a correct one, because this could then be used as a duplicate for many other questions. Having an incorrect answer at the top is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This callback is really messy. Just use async await instead:

```
async openAddBoardModal(){
    await this.setState({ boardAddModalShow: true });
    console.log(this.state.boardAddModalShow);
}
```

Comment: That makes no sense. React's `setState` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is right. `setState` doesn't return a promise, so it should NOT be awaited. That said, I think I can see why this is working for some people, because await puts the inner workings of setState on the call stack ahead of the rest of the function, so it gets processed first, and thus seems like the state has been set. If setState had or implements any new asynchronous calls, this answer would fail.To implement this function properly, you can use this: `await new Promise(resolve => this.setState({ boardAddModalShow: true }, () => resolve()))`

Comment: How the hell `async this.setState({})` solved my issue? We had working code, some more development has been done but nothing changed that part of the app. Only one of two objects in setState was getting updated, making it async returned functionality back and now both objects are correctly updating. I have freaking no idea what the hell was wrong.

Comment: I found this question, but this solution didn't work for me, I didn't solve my problem yet but I found a good read here: https://ozmoroz.com/2018/11/why-my-setstate-doesnt-work/

Comment: @OndřejŠevčík most likely a race-condition makes it looks like it works, but it'll possibly break again someday.

Comment: Calling await on a non-promise is the equivalent of calling `this.setState(..); await Promise.resolve();` which has the side effect of queueing all subsequent statements for immediate execution on the microtask queue. You could push out execution further by using the traditional event loop with an `await new Promise(rs => setTimeout(rs, 0))` but even, still, this is a hack, at best.

Comment: ho to do that in functinal component?

Comment: @Rupak you need to use Hooks

Answer (score 217):

Your state needs some time to mutate, and since `console.log(this.state.boardAddModalShow)` executes before the state mutates, you get the previous value as output. So you need to write the console in the callback to the `setState` function

```
openAddBoardModal() {
  this.setState({ boardAddModalShow: true }, function () {
    console.log(this.state.boardAddModalShow);
  });
}
```

`setState` is asynchronous. It means you can’t call it on one line and assume the state has changed on the next.

According to **[React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)**

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

#### Why would they make `setState` async

> This is because `setState` alters the state and causes rerendering. This
>   can be an expensive operation and making it synchronous might leave
>   the browser unresponsive.
>
> Thus the `setState` calls are asynchronous as well as batched for better
>   UI experience and performance.

Comment: Until now it is an great idea, BUT what if we can't use console.log because u're using eslint rules?

Comment: @maudev, eslint rules stop you to have console.logs so that they don't end up in production, but the above example is purely for debugging. and console.log and be replaced with an action which takes into account the updated state

Comment: What if the callback does not work as you said? mine does not!

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri this worked great for me, however I then tried to pass the state value as a prop into a child component, and when I `console.log` the prop, I get the same value as the original state.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I think it's worth pointing out that the value you set will be available in the **next render**. That's when you'll most likely be using the value for something useful rather than in the `setState` callback as shown here, which is mostly for debugging purposes.

Comment: hi there, how can I use a callback function if I'm setting the state like this setShowModal(1);

Comment: @VaibhavSidapara Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately/54069332#54069332https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately/54069332#54069332) post. Let me know if it helps

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks, I solved it yesterday. I used the same useEffect hook.

Answer (score 60):

**Fortunately** `setState()` takes a callback. And this is where we get updated state.

Consider this example.

```js
this.setState({ name: "myname" }, () => {                              
        //callback
        console.log(this.state.name) // myname
      });
```

So When callback fires, this.state is the updated state.
You can get `mutated/updated` data in callback.

Comment: You can also use this callback to pass any function, `initMap()`, for instance

Comment: Way to go! Finally solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this gives a warning in ReactJS functional component

Comment: don't depend on state and it will update the state and you will get update value through variable.

let categories = [...selectedCategory, value]
      setSelectedCategory(categories);
      setInputValue(categories)

using this piece of code you will get update value becuase you are not dependent on the state.

Answer (score 21):

For anyone trying to do this with hooks, you need `useEffect`.

```js
function App() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(5)
  const [y, setY] = useState(15) 

  console.log("Element is rendered:", x, y)

  // setting y does not trigger the effect
  // the second argument is an array of dependencies
  useEffect(() => console.log("re-render because x changed:", x), [x])

  function handleXClick() {
    console.log("x before setting:", x)
    setX(10)
    console.log("x in *line* after setting:", x)
  }

  return <>
    <div> x is {x}. </div>
    <button onClick={handleXClick}> set x to 10</button>
    <div> y is {y}. </div>
    <button onClick={() => setY(20)}> set y to 20</button>
  </>
}
```

Output:

```
Element is rendered: 5 15
re-render because x changed: 5
(press x button)
x before setting: 5
x in *line* after setting: 5
Element is rendered: 10 15
re-render because x changed: 10
(press y button)
Element is rendered: 10 20
```

[Live version](https://jscomplete.com/playground/s795178)

Answer (score 16):

Since setSatate is a asynchronous function so you need to console the state as a callback like this.

```
openAddBoardModal(){
    this.setState({ boardAddModalShow: true }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.boardAddModalShow)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.

`setState()` will always lead to a re-render unless `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false. If mutable objects are being used and conditional rendering logic cannot be implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()`, calling `setState()` only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

The first argument is an updater function with the signature:

```
(state, props) => stateChange
```

`state` is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state and props. For instance, suppose we wanted to increment a value in state by props.step:

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
    return {counter: state.counter + props.step};
});
```

Answer (score 5):

> Think of `setState()` as a **request** rather than an immediate command to
> update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
> delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
> does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

Check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more information.

In your case you have sent a **request** to update the state. It takes time for React to respond. If you try to immediately `console.log` the state, you will get the old value.

Answer (score 3):

The above solutions don't work for useState hooks.
One can use the below code

```
setState((prevState) => {
        console.log(boardAddModalShow)
        // call functions
        // fetch state using prevState and update
        return { ...prevState, boardAddModalShow: true }
    });
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me. I cannot translate it to my app. All I want to do is `setMyVariable(false)` hook variable immediately. Why is this so hard?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track the state is updating or not then the another way of doing the same thing is

```
_stateUpdated(){
  console.log(this.state. boardAddModalShow);
}

openAddBoardModal(){
  this.setState(
    {boardAddModalShow: true}, 
    this._stateUpdated.bind(this)
  );
}
```

This way you can call the method "_stateUpdated" every time you try to update the state for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are many good answers, if someone lands on this page searching for alternative to `useState` for implementing UI components like Navigation drawers which should be opened or closed based on user input, this answer would be helpful.

Though `useState` seems handy approach, the state is not set immediately and thus, your website or app looks laggy... And if your page is large enough, react is going to take long time to compute what all should be updated upon state change...

My suggestion is to use refs and directly manipulate the DOM when you want UI to change immediately in response to user action.

Using state for this purspose is really a bad idea in case of react.

Answer (score 1):

`setState()` is asynchronous. The best way to verify if the state is updating would be in the `componentDidUpdate()` and not to put a `console.log(this.state.boardAddModalShow)` after `this.setState({ boardAddModalShow: true })` .

according to [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately

Answer (score 1):

According to [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?#setstate)

> React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>   This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential `pitfall` and can potentially return the `existing` value due to `async` nature . 
>   Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback that is executed right after setState operation is successful.Generally we recommend using `componentDidUpdate()` for such logic instead.

### Example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter: 1
    };
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate fired");
    console.log("STATE", this.state);
  }

  updateState = () => {
    this.setState(
      (state, props) => {
        return { counter: state.counter + 1 };
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <button onClick={this.updateState}>Update State</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 this.setState({
    isMonthFee: !this.state.isMonthFee,
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.isMonthFee);
  })
```

Comment: This is exactly what the most upvoted answer explains, but without any explanation and 3 years late. Please do not post duplicate answers **unless you have something relevant to add to it.**

Answer (score -1):

when i was running the code and checking my output at console it showing the that it is undefined.
After i search around and find something that worked for me.

```
componentDidUpdate(){}
```

I added this method in my code after constructor().
check out the life cycle of react native workflow.

https://images.app.goo.gl/BVRAi4ea2P4LchqJ8

Answer (score -2):

Yes because setState is an asynchronous function. The best way to set state right after you write set state is by using Object.assign like this: 
For eg you want to set a property isValid to true, do it like this

---

> Object.assign(this.state, { isValid: true })

---

**You can access updated state just after writing this line.**

Comment: Don't do this, [it mutates the current state, which is an anti-pattern.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37755997/1218980)