# How to save previous state/ page data before going to another page in React JS

Tags: reactjs

```js
this.state = {
            name: '',
            color: '',
            description: '',
            beacons: []
        };
        
         handleColors = (item) => {
          this.setState({
              color: item.value
          });

      };

    handleBeaconChange = (beacons) => {
          this.setState({
              beacons
          });
          
      };

    handleInputChange(event) {

        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });

    }
    
    <div className="mb-1  margin-input">
                    <span className=" form-font div-width">NAME<span className="font-css top">*</span></span>
                      <input type="text"
                       className="form-control margin-select" 
                       placeholder="Name"
                       value={this.state.name}
                        name="name" 
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                       />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                         <span className=" form-font div-width">
                            COLOR</span>
                        <Select
                          className="margin-select"
                          value={this.state.color}
                          options={colorValues}
                          onChange={this.handleColors}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1  margin-input">
                    <span className=" form-font div-width">DESCRIPTION</span>
                      <textarea 
                      className="form-control margin-select" 
                      placeholder="Description"
                      value={this.state.description}
                        name="description" 
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <h3 className="">{this.props.label}</h3>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                         <span className=" form-font div-width">
                            BEACON (s)</span>
                        <Select.Async 
                          multi={true} 
                          className="margin-select"
                          value={this.state.beacons}
                          loadOptions={getBeacons}
                          onChange={this.handleBeaconChange}/>

                          <div className="panel-body">
                        <a href={'/new-beacon'} className="pull-right">Add Beacon</a>
                      </div>

                    </div>
```

[image]This is the image.
Now i just wanted to save previous form data before going to another page
Like for example in this picture i had entered name and color values in the fields and when i click on "Add beacon link", it will route me to another form but the values i entered in this form were lost when i will come back to it.
Any solutions regarding that?

Comment: Either you can make use of redux or save in localStorage

Comment: How to do that with redux? or localstorage?
I'm already using redux actions reducers but how with redux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of Redux to achieve the same. What you need to do is to save the form states in redux store rather than the component `localState` itself

You reducer will look something like

```
const initialState = {
      name: '',
            color: '',
            description: '',
            beacons: []
}
const BeaconForm = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch(action.type) {
          case 'UPDATE_BEACON_FORM_VALUE': 
               return {
                    ...state, [action.newVal.key]: action.newVal.value
               }
          default: return state
      }
}

export default BeaconForm
```

And then have an action

```
export function updataFormValue(updatedVal) {
       return { type: 'UPDATE_BEACON_FORM_VALUE', newVal: updatedVal}
}
```

And in the compoennt

```
handleInputChange(event) {

    var data = {[event.target.name]: event.target.value}
    this.props.updataFormValue(data);

}
```

Apart from this you need to make your component `Redux` compatible with `connect, mapStateToProps , etc` which I assume you already know

And then instead of setting input value from state you will set it from props that youu get from redux store

Comment: thanks but this approach i think will be complex compared to local storage?
How to achieve with local storage?

Comment: but I'm thinking of to go with local storage because of lack of time actually

Comment: On `localStorage.setItem('FormData', JSON.stringify(data))` where data is  `var data = {...this.state}` and later you can setback to state after retireving it like `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FormData'))`

Comment: i tried this and i just done console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('FormData'))), this is showing like for example if i had typed "hello", it will show in console as "hell", that is, one character less than being typed

Comment: so you are copying the state after setting right. I that ase setState teakes time to mutate,Do it in callback

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/change-state-on-click-react-js/41278440#41278440

Comment: handleInputChange(event) {

        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });

        localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(this.state));
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formData')))

    }

componentWillMount = () => {
           
            if(localStorage.formData) {
              console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.formData))
            }
        }; , i did this actually

Comment: i got it but how o show now those set values in local storage in input fields again

Comment: In componentWillMount and fetch the localStorage value and set the state based on them

Comment: just a problem with setting that
omitting last character before setting

Comment: Doing it in setState callback will solve the problem i think

Comment: If this.state.beacons work, it will also work.make sure to set state correctly

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294748/conditional-api-call-and-send-data-in-react-select