# this.setState does not update state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use `this.setState` within `handleFormSubmit` however `this.setState` isn't updating and I'm not sure why. If I run `console.log(updatePosition)` before `this.setState` I can that all the data is there. What am I missing? I use similar code for handleChange and I don't have problems.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  let uniqueId = moment().valueOf();

  this.state = {
    careerHistoryPositions: [{company: '', uniqueId: uniqueId, errors: {} }],
  };

  this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
}




handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { careerHistoryPositions } = this.state;

  const updatePosition = this.state.careerHistoryPositions.map((careerHistoryPosition) => {
    const errors = careerHistoryValidation(careerHistoryPosition);
    return { ...careerHistoryPosition, errors: errors  };
  });

  console.log(updatePosition)
  this.setState({ careerHistoryPositions: updatePosition });
}
```

Comment: You code seems fine, where do you check whether the state has updated or not

Comment: after this.setState

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.setState doesn't update value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/this-setstate-doesnt-update-value)

Comment: In that case its a duplicate of the question I have marked . Check the answer on that question

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even think of that. Will do.

Comment: @bp123 this actually depends if your extending on PureComponent or React.Component. If your using React.Component your code should re-render every time you call this.setState() method. But if your using PureComponent and in your code if your object does not change. It won't re-render. https://60devs.com/pure-component-in-react.html

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the state isn't updated immediately. If you want to check if it's updated use callback function. Something as follows:

```
this.setState({ careerHistoryPositions: updatePosition }, () => console.log(this.state.careerHistoryPositions);
```

From the docs :

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should show how you are calling `handleFormSubmit` chances are that it's bound to a Dom event. So `this` is not the class/component, instead if you `console.log(this);` you'll see that it's the Dom element, the form element.

To make your code work as intended, in your component `constructor()` method, add this to rebind the handler function to the react component's class method, and you'll have access to `this.state` and `this.setState()`

```
this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
```

Comment: As the OP says, he is able to see the correct O/P for `console.log(updatePosition)` , it means he has done the appropriate binding. So thats not a problem. Check the Duplicate question

Comment: Yup he just updated the code snippet a minute ago showing the bind. Thanks.