# state is not being set in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I want to access the refs from the render function, and set it to the state.

Here is my code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(); 
            this.arr = this.generateTimelineArray();
            this.state = {el : 'empty'};
        }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
          el: this.refs.el
        });
        console.log(this.state.el)
    }
render() {
    return (
      <div  className="timeline__container--line" ref="el" ></div>
    ); 
  }
```

I can `console.log(this.refs.el)` and the value is logged. But i have to save it to constructor to pass it to another component.

Problem is that the state is not being changed.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW why do you want to put dom element reference to component's state?

Comment: I need to get offset of the div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.setState doesn't update value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/this-setstate-doesnt-update-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setState` is async. [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate). If you want to see updated state use callback.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
          el: this.refs.el
        }, () => console.log(this.state.el));
    }
```

Comment: It is great, but why do I have to console.log() in order to set state, is it possible to do callback without console.log ?

Comment: @Giedrius You don't have to log. It's just if you want to use **updated** state you need to use a callback. But it is all up to you what exactly you want to do with the new state

Comment: Ok, last question then, how do i pass an updated state as a prop to another component ?  Do i also have to use callback funtion <Component props=" () => this.state.el"/> ?

Comment: And you can't have element reference in constructor. Because when constructor is called before render.

Comment: I recommend you to extract dom information (offset) and pass this value to child. So you start from `this.state = {offset: null}`, then check in render function `this.state.offset && <Child offset={this.state.offset} />` and in `componentDidMount` you `this.setState(() => ({offset: getOffset(this.refs.el)}))`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, This question has multiple dupliates existing on SO. Kindly mark them as duplicates instead of answering them

Answer (score 0):

Like Yury said, `this.setState` is asynchronous. Apart from a callback function, you can use a boolean state variable and check for that in render:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(); 
            this.arr = this.generateTimelineArray();
            this.state = {el : 'empty', flag : true};
        }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
          el: this.refs.el,
          flag : false
        });
        console.log(this.state.el)
    }
render() {
    return (
      this.state.flag == false &&
      <div  className="timeline__container--line" ref="el" ></div>
    ); 
  }
```

This will now only render once the asynchronous setState has completed.