# React setState won't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to set the state from within the if statement but it wont do this.
In result I need to update state from within if statement where I can receive longitude and latitude coordinates, but it won't save the state. If I echo in console outside of if statement I will read only first setState value form componentWillMount. What's the issue there? What I'm doing wrong here? 
So here is the structure:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        location: {
            name: 'Riga'
        }
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (!!navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

            this.setState({
                location: {
                    name: 'Sigulda'
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        alert('ERROR on GEOLOCATION');
    }

    console.log(this.state.location);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/this-setstate-doesnt-mutate-state-immediately/41278440#41278440

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setState` actions are asynchronous.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

You should use `setState` callback function:

```
this.setState({
  location: {
    name: 'Sigulda'
  }
}, () => console.log(this.state.location));
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, that solved my issue!!!

Answer (score 3):

`setState` is asynchronous:

```
 this.setState({
                location: {
                    name: 'Sigulda'
                }
            }, () => console.log(this.state.location));
```

Use the callback of `setState` to determine changes

Comment: Perfect ans.. setState is async and you can pass a callback here as demonstrated above incase you want to use the updated state

Comment: Thank you for explanation, that solved my issue!!!

Comment: You might run into other issues though, like @MayankShukla already said. I'm not familiar with you `geolocation` but your `setState` issue is fixed