# update array of json in react js state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a multiselect dropdown. whenever I select an option I need to add that data to state.
when I click the first option I get data like

```
[{id:"1", name:"Ind"}]
```

when I click the second option I get data like (currently two options are selected)

```
[{id:"1", name:"Ind"}, {id:"2", name:"Aus"}]

this.state = {
    selectedCountries: []
};
```

in the onChange of multiselect I call the below function

```
handleChange = (options) => {
    var output = [];
    if(options !== null && options !== undefined){
        console.log(options); //    [{id:"1", name:"Ind"}, {id:"2", name:"Aus"}]
        this.setState(prevState => {
            selectedCountries:options
        });
    }
};
```

Its not working.

I am expecting it like this

```
selectedCountries:[
    {
        id:"1",
        name:"Ind"
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        name:"Aus"
    }
]
```

How to achieve this through reactjs?

Comment: Change  this.setState(prevState => {
            selectedCountries:options
        }); to this.setState({selectedCountries: options})

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org) but an array of objects.

Comment: its ok.array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setState` syntax is incorrect

```
    this.setState({
        selectedCountries:options
    });
```

You need to make use of updater function only when you need to update the state based on the previous state and in that case you need to return an object from the updater function which you aren't doing

It would look like

```
    const newlyAddedOption = {id:"3", name:"UK"}
    this.setState(prevState => {
        return { selectedCountries:[...prevState.selectedCountries, newlyAddedOption]}
    });
```

or

```
    const newlyAddedOption = {id:"3", name:"UK"}
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        selectedCountries: [...prevState.selectedCountries, newlyAddedOption]
    }));
```

However this isn't currently useful to you since you get all the options together at once.

Comment: if i select 3 options only 2 values are updated in the state. what could be the reason?

Comment: Are you logging those after setting state. You might want to check this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/calling-setstate-doesnt-mutate-state-immediately/41278440#41278440

Comment: when i select a new option i ll get all the selected data like [{id:"1", name:"Ind"}, {id:"2", name:"Aus"}]

Comment: Did you check the question that I linked in my above comment