# How can i call this state synchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that react doesn't update state immediately then can someone tell me how i can log this state synchronously as my state is not a boolean and this answer didn't help me [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately). Also i don't understand why after clicking on prev button it increments the value first and then it decrements

```
    class A extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: 1
        }
      }


      handleNext() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          value: prevState.value + 1
        }));
        console.log(this.state.value);
      }

      handlePrev() {
        if(this.state.value > 1) {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            value: prevState.value - 1
          }));
        }
        console.log(this.state.value);
      }

     render() {
       <Button bsStyle="primary" id="prev" onClick={() => this.handlePrev()}>Prev</Button>
       <Button bsStyle="primary" id="next" onClick={() => this.handleNext()}>Next</Button>
}
```

Comment: It appears your question is directly answered in the question you linked to

Comment: Also, your example "works" as it should, clicking prev does not increment the value first and then decrement. http://jsbin.com/hotafikiko/edit?html,js,output - but also, the exact code you pasted does not work directly as it's missing some curly braces and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `setState` is a callback that executes after the state has updated.

```
  handleNext() {
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 }, () => ({
      console.log(this.state.value);
    });
  }
```

From [the setState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

Answer (score 2):

`setState` takes a callback as its second argument.

```
handleNext() {
   this.setState(prevState => ({
          value: prevState.value + 1
        }),() => console.log('updated', this.state.value));

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You code is fine, try printing `this.state.value` in your render function.

Example:

```
class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 1,
    };
  }

  handleNext() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      value: prevState.value + 1,
    }));
  }

  handlePrev() {
    if (this.state.value > 1) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        value: prevState.value - 1,
      }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{ value }</h2>
        <button id="prev" onClick={() => this.handlePrev()}>Prev</button>
        <button id="next" onClick={() => this.handleNext()}>Next</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It seems like your `handlePrev` is incrementing then decrementing because you're constantly printing the previous state. So when you decrement you are printing the result of the previous increment.

```
|---------------------|-------------------------|
|    Current State    |     Your console.log    |
|---------------------|-------------------------|
|          1          |                         | init
|---------------------|-------------------------|
|          2          |            1            | increment
|---------------------|-------------------------|
|          3          |            2            | increment
|---------------------|-------------------------|
|          2          |            3            | decrement
|---------------------|-------------------------|
```