# setState and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sometimes setState doesnt working all by itself and i am adding small timeouts to do it. 
My first question is;

1-) Why setState sometimes doesnt working without a delay?

2-) Is it correct to add setTimeout? - And its small amount of delay like 10 ms, its nothing, but it makes my code to work and state to update.

When i was coding in Angular1, we were using $timeout sometimes for scope to apply this changes. But it was okay to do so, in React i am not sure about this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide a few lines of code of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: setState is asynchronous. Meaning setState doesnt guarantee that this.state.property will immediately reflect the updated value. There is a callback param in setState that will be fired after state update.

Comment: Are you calling `setState` in the constructor of a class component?

Comment: @CapitanFindus - Actually it is very simple. Just try to updating state but without setTimeout it isnt working, what can cause this?

Comment: Can you please show your relevant code. It looks like a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately/41278440#41278440

Comment: @ssk - I know, but what can callback actually do? I am console.logging some success message, it is coming but its still not updating state value.

Comment: instead of setTimeout try console logging in setState callback. For Eg: `this.setState({name: 'abc' }, () => console.log(this.state.name))`

Comment: @ssk - it is says and shows changed state but at first change, it is not showing in view. just in state. in view it turns to  default state again. strange behaviour. i wonder what can cause this behaviour

Comment: Show us your code! Stop wondering what causes this behavior, show us your code so we can help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're attempting to call `setState` in a `render`. This is bad because `render` occurs immediately following state updates. It causes a render loop. You should not use a `setTimeout` to do this either. That causes React to stop warning you because it can no longer detect the issue. This will cause large random bugs in your app.

Your symptoms are a sign that you need to push the state up into container components.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why there is a delay in setting the state is that 3 lifecycle method of ReactJS are called while setting the state.
setTimeout is a way to get the current value of the state which has just been set, However another alternative would be that you can create a callback function inside the setState to get the current value.
Use of setTimeout must be always be avoided until and unless there is no other alternative.

example:
`this.setState({show:true},()=>{console.log(this.state.show)})`

Comment: setTimeout is not a good way to get the value of state. React batches state updates. It may or may not have been set when the setTimeout executes.