# Variable value is not passing in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am new to React JS. I am facing an issue regarding a variable value is not passing to a function.

Here is my code.

```js
class Main extends React.Component{

  state = {
    setType : ""
  }
  
  
  getType(getValue){
    let type = ''
    
    if(getValue === 'win'){
      type = 'win'
    }
    
    else if(getValue === 'lose'){
      type = 'lose'
    }
    
    else {
      type = ""
    }
    
    return type
  }
  
  
  componentDidMount(){
  let type = this.getType('win')
    this.setState({
      setType : type
    })
    
    if(this.props.match.path === '/win'){ 
        this.setState({
          setType : 'win'
        })
    }
    
    if(this.props.match.path === '/lose'){ 
        this.setState({
          setType : 'lose'
        })
    }
  }
  
  this.props.detail(this.state.setType)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

If I write `this.props.detail(type)` instead of `this.props.detail(this.state.setType)`

then it works fine. also I want to set `setType` value on url Hit. so that if matching url hits, then it's state value also changes and pass to `this.props.detail()`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState` is a asynchronous call .By the time your program control gets to `this.props.detail()` the setState might not have been completed. so your `this.state.setType` might not have been updated with the new value. that is why your type is having the correct value but your `this.state.setType` isn't.

**Edit**

set state like this:

```
this.setState({
      setType : type
    }, () => {
        this.props.detail(this.state.setType)
    })
```

Comment: thank you for your time and answer. How can I solve this issue ? I am totally new to React JS.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is a async function. There are changes that when you are calling `detail` function, that time state are not updated and you have old value in state.

Please write clear and update state once, and do operation on callback.

#### Example

```
componentDidMount(){
  let type = this.getType('win')

    if(this.props.match.path === '/win'){ 
        type = 'win'
    }

    if(this.props.match.path === '/lose'){ 
        type = 'lose'
    }

    this.setState({
      setType : type
    }, () => {
        this.props.detail(this.state.setType)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things that you need to consider while implementing the above

1. componentDidMount is only called once when the component mounts and not on subsequent re-renders
2. [`setState doesn't update the state immediately and is asynchronous`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately/41278440#41278440)

So in your case you would need to use `componentWillReceiveProps/componentDidUpdate` to update state on `match` prop change and second pass back value to `detail` in setState callback or a stored value which is being set to state.

```js
class Main extends React.Component{

  state = {
    setType : ""
  }
  
  
  getType(getValue){
    let type = ''
    
    if(getValue === 'win'){
      type = 'win'
    }
    
    else if(getValue === 'lose'){
      type = 'lose'
    }
    
    else {
      type = ""
    }
    
    return type
  }
  
  
componentDidMount(){
    let type = this.getType('win')
    this.setState({
      setType : type
    })
    const newState = type;
    if(this.props.match.path === '/win'){ 
        newState = 'win'
    }
    
    if(this.props.match.path === '/lose'){ 
        newState = 'lose'
    }
    this.setState({setType: newState});
    this.props.detail(newState)
  }
  

componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if(this.props.match.path !== prevProps.match.path) {
            const newState = this.state.setType;
            if(this.props.match.path === '/win'){ 
                newState = 'win'
            }

            if(this.props.match.path === '/lose'){ 
                newState = 'lose'
            }
        }    
        this.setState({setType: newState}, () => {
            this.props.detail(this.state.setType)
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```