# map is not a function ERROR after using push on an array in REACT

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, push

I pushed an element to an array in a function( event),
after pushing this element to the array I am getting this error,

```
handleAddList(s) {
  this.setState({lists :this.state.lists.push(s) });
  console.log(this.state.lists);
}
```

lists.map  is not a function.
list a react component

if I write it as this

```
handleAddList(s) {
  this.setState({lists :['something','something else']});
  console.log(this.state.lists);
}
```

But when I define lists manually it works well. Just when I push a new element in the array I get this error. Also if push destroys the array.
Best regards

Comment: Using concat instead of push would do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `push` is the length of the array, which is not what you want. You want to create a new array with the new object in it instead:

```
handleAddList(s) {
  this.setState(
    previousState => {
      return { lists: [...previousState.lists, s] };
    },
    () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`push` returns the length of the array after appending the element and not an array, what you need is `concat`

```
handleAddList(s) {
    this.setState({lists :this.state.lists.concat([s]) });
}
```

Also [`setState doesn't update the state immediately`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately/41278440#41278440) You would need to use callback like

```
handleAddList(s) {
    this.setState({lists :this.state.lists.concat([s]) }, () => { console.log(this.state.lists)});
}
```

Comment: thank you very much my dear friend. that was a great help. thanks

Comment: @mojtaba1 Glad to have helped :-)