# How to alert a Selected Record using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to alert an email records each time a particular Email is selected using reactjs. To this effect, I have created Reactjs function.

The issue is that it displays error:

> Cannot read property email of undefined at fetchEmail

each time I tried to select a particular email.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

</head>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
var MainBox  = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <App/>
        );
    }
});


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super() 
      this.state = {
 //isLoading: true,
        //data: []
      }

  }
  componentDidMount() {

  }

fetchEmail(){
//this.email = '';
alert(this.email);

}


  render() {


    return (
<div id='container'>

<select name="this.email" id="this.email" value={this.email} onChange={this.fetchEmail} >

  <option value=''>Select Email</option>
                           <option value='tony@gmail.com'>Tony Email</option>
                           <option value='mich@gmail.com'>Michael Email</option>
                           <option value='frank@gmail.com'>Frank Email</option>
 </select>

  </div>

    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <MainBox />,
    document.querySelector("#app")
);
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the changed email string value from the `<select>` from the event object passed via `onChange()` to `fetchEmail()`. Add an argument to `fetchEmail()` to capture that passed event. You can retrieve the value of the `<select>` by targeting `target.value` of that event object. This is explained and demonstrated well in the official documentation on [React Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html):

```
fetchEmail(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

It's somewhat unclear what you are attempting to do, but it looks like you are attempting to store a value for `email` on your component, update it when a change event happens on `<select>`, and use that value in some way. In React you can do this through state. You will need to make a few changes. This including adding an `email` property to your `state`. Updating the `value` property on the `<select>` to use `this.state.email` instead of `this.email`. Also you would use `setState()` to update the component's local state values. In this case updating `email` to match the `e.target.value`. Finally you could then access this `email` value using `this.state.email` instead of `this.email`.

Here is how the revised component could look:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      email: ''
    };

    this.fetchEmail = this.fetchEmail.bind(this);
  }

  fetchEmail(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
    // do no attempt to do console.log(this.state.email) right here, it will not be updated right away, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.email}</p>
        <select name="email" id="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.fetchEmail} >
          <option value=''>Select Email</option>
          <option value='tony@gmail.com'>Tony Email</option>
          <option value='mich@gmail.com'>Michael Email</option>
          <option value='frank@gmail.com'>Frank Email</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n5qrkq) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
this.fetchEmail = this.fetchEmail.bind(this);
```

at the constructor.

If you are directly trying to alert the mail without using the internal state, you can follow this piece of code.

```
    class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: ''
        };
        this.fetchEmail = this.fetchEmail.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <select name="this.email" id="this.email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.fetchEmail} >

                    <option value=''>Select Email</option>
                    <option value='tony@gmail.com'>Tony Email</option>
                    <option value='mich@gmail.com'>Michael Email</option>
                    <option value='frank@gmail.com'>Frank Email</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
    fetchEmail(e) {
        this.setState({email: e.currentTarget.value});
        alert(e.currentTarget.value);
    }
}
```