# Undefined getting value from fetch request in a JSON file using REACT.JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm coming from a Vue environment I'm a bit confused with this,
I read some other question similar to this but I couldn't make it work,

why I can't echo out the value of a nested object getting from a fetch request?

I `console.log` after `setState` and I got the values but in the render is undefined,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      articles: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch("./articles.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          article: result.blog.article
        });
        console.log(
          "componentDidMount__this.state.article=",
          this.state.article.link.title
        ); //this gets the value
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    //let articleTitle;
    // this gets error ----> console.log(this.state.article.link.title);
    // because .link is undefined

    // console.log(this.state.article);
    // if (this.state.article !== "undefined") {
    //   console.log("wait what?..");
    // if I changed the state in fetch why this stil
    //   articleTitle = this.state.article.link.title;
    // } else {
    //   articleTitle = "";
    // }

    // I assign "this.state.article.link.title" to a variable so I can avoid the error,
    //
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/*<h1>{articleTitle}</h1> */}
        <h1>{this.state.article.link.title}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**articles.json**

```
{
  "blog": {
    "article": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": " 1 lorem ipsum",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "image": {
        "desktop": "https://via.placeholder.com/900x500?text=desktop",
        "tablet": "https://via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=tablet",
        "mobile": "https://via.placeholder.com/320x320?text=mobile"
      },
      "link": {
        "title": "lorem link",
        "url": "#"
      },
      "author": {
        "avatar": "https://via.placeholder.com/125x125?text=125x125",
        "name": "lorem ipsum"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wo65w21kl5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Comment: it's a totally different question...also the answer wont solve my problem... I dont need to console.log in a callback...I can console.log and see the data...the problem is that is render undefined

Comment: updated codesandbox [https://codesandbox.io/s/ryo89x6lp](https://codesandbox.io/s/ryo89x6lp).. in react component, the methods are called in the following order when an instance of a component is being created and inserted into the DOM

`1. constructor()`
`2. static getDerivedStateFromProps()`
`3. render()`
`4. componentDidMount()`

ie, the `render` method executed before the `componentDidMount` method..

Answer (score 0):

You have to put check before using dynamic states in render as it is called on both component mount and update.

This should work fine:

`{this.state.isLoading ? '' : this.state.article.link.title}`

Comment: this solve my problem... but why I got it and they dont https://scrimba.com/p/p7P5Hd/c79Jask ?

Comment: @Marcogomesr In that video state is initiated with an empty object `character: {}`, also there's a check in the end as I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `this.state.article.link.title` is being referenced when `this.state.article === undefined`.

The solution is to retrieve `this.state.article.link.title` in a safer manner.

This is typically achieved by leveraging [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation). I've also used [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) in the example below.

Assigning default values to `this.state` is also recommended, especially when dealing with indeterminate data.

```
// Default `this.state`.
this.state = {
  article: {link: {title: ''}},
  articles: {},
  isLoading: true,
}

// Safe retrieval of `title`.
const {article = {}} = this.state
const {link = {}} = article.link
const title = link.title || ''
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY this**

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

    import "./styles.css";

    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
      state = {
        isLoading: true,
        articles: {}
      };
      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        fetch("./articles.json")
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result => {
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              articles: result.blog.article
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }

      render() {
        let Test = this.state.articles ? (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>{this.state.articles.title}</h1>
          </div>
        ) : null;

        console.log(this.state.articles.title);
        return <div>{Test}</div>;
      }
    }

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that render method is invoked three times before fetch method finish, so in render method `this.state.articles` is empty object. You also wonders why guy from the tutorial does not have this issue, well in  [tutorial you mentioned](http://scrimba.com/p/p7P5Hd/c79Jask) object: `this.state.character.name` was used and in your code `this.state.articles.link.title`. This is the difference, because it is acceptable to use `this.state.character.name` (it refers to property from empty object so it will return undefined, whereas your `this.state.article.link.title` (it tries to access to property on object that does not exist). You can check it in console:

```
const obj = {};
console.log(obj.property); //undefined
console.log(obj.link.title); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```