# Child setState does not work when calling Parent method

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React so sorry if this is a bad question. I am having trouble with changing the state of a child component then calling a method that changes the state of the parent component. Right now when I trigger the method that is supposed to change states the parent state changes as it should but the child state does not change at all.

When I remove the state change on the Parent component the child component changes as it should.

Here is the parent component (edited to remove code not related to the problem)

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loginModalName: "Log in"
        }
        this.bindedUpdateModalName = this.updateModalName.bind(this)
    }

    updateModalName(name) {
        console.log(name);
        this.setState({
            loginModalName: name
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Child loginSwitch = {this.bindedUpdateModalName}/>
        );
    }
}
```

and here is the child component

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoggingIn: true
        }
    }

    toggleLoggingIn = () => {
        this.setState({
            isLoggingIn: !this.state.isLoggingIn
        });
        console.log(this.state.isLoggingIn);
        this.props.loginSwitch(this.state.isLoggingIn ? "Log in" : "Register");
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onClick={this.toggleLoggingIn} type="link" style={{paddingLeft: 0}}>register now!</Button>
        );
    }
```

There are no error messages, but my logs show

```
true
Log In
```

every time I click the button

Comment: this is because setState is async. You need to wait for the state update to happen or use a change variable to both set state and call the next function

Comment: Issue is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `setState` is async. You need to wait for the state change to happen (second callback option for `setState`, or `componentDidUpdate`) or you can use a variable like `isLogin` to hold the new state value. Change your handler to this

```
toggleLoggingIn = () => {
    const isLogin = !this.state.isLoggingIn
    this.setState({
        isLoggingIn: isLogin
    });
    console.log(this.props.loginSwitch);
    this.props.loginSwitch(isLogin ? "Log in" : "Register");
};
```

[**Check it out in action!**](https://jsfiddle.net/ayv5mbsr/1/)

The issue you were experiencing is trying to use local state on an `antd` form. You should either use parent state and pass as a prop, or use the `antd` way of updating "state" on the HOC

Comment: Thanks for the help, but using the code you supplied does not change the results.

Comment: @JacobHicks not sure what the issue is. [**Here's a fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ayv5mbsr/1/) showing it work

Comment: huh. Im not quite sure how to move on from here then

Comment: Can you replicate the issue you are having on a fiddle so I can review / help?

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue with CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/oeisd?fontsize=14, Im beginning to think this may be an odd issue with Ant Design

Comment: you aren't using the `isLogin` variable in the `loginSwitch` call

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194261/discussion-between-jacob-hicks-and-john-ruddell).

Answer (score 3):

As John mentioned `setState` is [async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). However, `setState` takes a second parameter that is a [callback function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to call after is has updated the state.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

Try this:

```
toggleLoggingIn = () => {
    const isLogin = !this.state.isLoggingIn
    this.setState(
        {
            isLoggingIn: !this.state.isLoggingIn
        },

        // Callback to run after state has been updated 
        () => {
            console.log(this.state.isLoggingIn);
            this.props.loginSwitch(this.state.isLoggingIn ? "Log in" : "Register");
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, using this code changes the log output to `false Register` but it still does not solve my problem as it still does not toggle between true and false

Comment: @JacobHicks I've fixed the code to match you're example