# how to update the state of an array

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

I want to remove data once the clear button is clicked. so for that i have set the state with empty array  using `data:[]` . when i console log it, it gives me an empty array which means the state is updating. but the moment it goes here `this.props.form.setFieldsValue` line. the state is again updating with the old values (props values). 
if anyone know how to fix this please tell. thanks

```
Clear = async () => {
       await this.setState({
            textOne: 0,
            texttwo: 0,
            textthree: 0,
            data:[]
        });

        this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
            number_field_one: '',
        });

    }
```

```
<div style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "3%", marginBottom: "1%" }}>
  <span>
    {getFieldDecorator("number_field_one", {})(
      <Select
        onChange={e => {
          this.setState({ ID: e });
        }}
        filterOption={(input, option) =>
          option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        }
      >
        {Options}
      </Select>
    )}
  </span>

  {this.state.data ? (
    <div
      style={{ float: "right", width: "30%", height: 280, overflowY: "scroll" }}
    >
      <List
        loading={this.props.loading}
        size="small"
        bordered
        dataSource={this.state.data}
        renderItem={item => <List.Item>{item}</List.Item>}
      />
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div
      style={{ float: "right", width: "30%", height: 280, overflowY: "scroll" }}
    >
      <List
        loading={this.props.loading}
        size="small"
        bordered
        dataSource={data}
        renderItem={item => <List.Item>{item}</List.Item>}
      />
    </div>
  )}
</div>
 <Button onClick={this.Clear} type="danger" >Clear</Button>
```

Comment: Are you using Formik? can you paste the full code here?

Comment: Can you remove async-await in your Clear function? It is not required. That is not allowing to do setState immediately.

Comment: @Nayanshah i used it because the setState doesn't update the state immediately.

Comment: @123t - setState updates the state immediately, and based on state change, the dependent component lifecycle changes as well. So if you do async-await, then your react component lifecycle will not work properly and the state will not be updated timely, that's why you are seeing old state instead of empty array(new state).

Comment: okay i removed it but i have still got the same issue . and when i console log the this.state.data it shows undefined so that means my state is not updating ! why is that ?

Comment: @Nayanshah i used that async according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately    is it a bad practise ?

Comment: In most cases, setState will work fine without callback functions.

Comment: @bravemaster so that means is it okay to use async there ?

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb my code is too long

Comment: Can you just paste that file? i mean the code above that clear function?

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb i have updated the code ! you want to see the function, above the clear function right ?

Comment: Would be convenient for all of us if you can paste the full code or create a minimal example in codesandbox