# setState updates state however callback function as second argument will not execute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am changing the logic of my sign in feature. I have one button that is to `signUp` and one to `signIn`. `signUp` works but `signIn` does not and I am not sure why when they both lead to the same function which kicks off an api request to log the user in.

state:

```
state = {
    controls: {
      email: {
        elementType: "input-email",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Email Address"
        },
        value: localStorage.getItem("email") || "",
        validation: {
          required: true, // must not be empty
          isEmail: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      password: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "Password"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 6
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      }
    },
    isSignUp: true,
    rememberMe: false
  };
```

Sign in form code with two buttons:

```
 return (
      <div className={classes.Auth}>
        {isLoggedIn}
        {errorMessage}
        <p className={classes.signUp}>Sign up to create a burger</p>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {form}
          <Button btnType="Success">SIGN UP </Button>
        </form>
        <p className={classes.subText}>
          Already have an account? Switch to sign in below:
        </p>
        <Button clicked={this.signInHandler} btnType="Danger">
          SIGN IN
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
```

Handlers for both buttons:

`Signup` handler (this works):

```
  handleSubmit = event => {
    this.props.onAuth(
      this.state.controls.email.value,
      this.state.controls.password.value,
      this.state.isSignUp
    );
    event.preventDefault();
  };
```

`SignIn` handler which then calls `handleSubmit` also:

```
 signInHandler = () => {
    this.setState(
      { isSignUp: false }, // should be false to kick off the api for the SignIn
      () => {                        // callback
        this.handleSubmit(); // calls the method above which signs user in 
      }
    );
  };
```

I followed this `stackoverflow` thread to write this part:
[setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

This is the error I get when I click the SIGN IN button

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: what is the value || type of the event when passing through the handleSubmit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `handleSubmit = event =>`, but not sending the event to handle submit, add it to the flow

---

```
 <Button clicked={e=>this.signInHandler(e)} ... />



 signInHandler = e => {
    this.setState(
      { isSignUp: false }, // should be false to kick off the api for the SignIn
      () => {                        // callback
        this.handleSubmit(e); // calls the method above which signs user in 
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: Ok I will try that. How come I don't need to pass an event to the  `handleSubmit` handler though when that button is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the event argument. This should work:

```
signInHandler = (e) => {
   this.setState(
     { isSignUp: false }, // should be false to kick off the API for the SignIn
     () => {                        // callback
       this.handleSubmit(e); // calls the method above which signs user in 
     }
   );
 };
```