# How can I force setState to perform changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to partially change the state of my component, but unfortunately it isn't performing as I'm excpecting.

I initialize the state in this way :

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array: [],
            status: false,
            interval: null,
            animations: [],
            algorithm: null 
        }
    }
```

The way I try to use it

```
if(this.state.status === false){
            this.change_style(text);

            //The change
            this.setState({status: true, animations: [], algorithm: "Bubble_Sort"});

            const arr = this.state.array.slice();
            this.bubble_sort_and_push(this.state.animations, arr);
            this.animate(this.state.animations);
        }
```

After some research I saw that `setState` only changes the state if there is an actual change between the prev state to the new one (In my case it does have differences)

So I can't really grasp why the changes don't go through.

I tried changing only one of the fields

```
 if(this.state.status === false){
            this.change_style(text);
            console.log(this.state.status);
            //The change
            this.setState({status: true})
            console.log(this.state.status);

            const arr = this.state.array.slice();
            this.bubble_sort_and_push(this.state.animations, arr);
            this.animate(this.state.animations);
        }
```

There was no difference between the `console.log` calls, but the change did happen.

How can I make the `setState` perform the moment I invoke it?

I have tried using `forceUpdate()` and read that it has connection to `DidComponentUpdate`, but can't really figure out how to connect them to work like I expect.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately/41278440#41278440)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the code in a `callback` if you want it to be execute immediately after `setState`, your code would be something like this in `Class Component`:

```
 if(this.state.status === false){
            this.change_style(text);
            console.log(this.state.status);
            //The change
            this.setState({status: true}, function(){
                console.log(this.state.status);

                const arr = this.state.array.slice();
                this.bubble_sort_and_push(this.state.animations, arr);
                this.animate(this.state.animations);
            });
  }
```

Comment: I can understand it, but sadly I don't really need the `console.log` call, I'm trying to make the state change, so i could use it in the lines that come after.

Comment: what do you mean by `in the lines that come after` ? all the code inside `function callback` would be execute after `state change`.

Answer (score 0):

**setState** is asynchronous, you should never assume that changes will be immediate :

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

React does some operations in the background, like bundling state changes together to be more efficient (update things in bulk).

In a functional component the solution would be to use the **useEffect** hook, with a non empty dependencies array. React would trigger **useEffect** when a variable in the dependencies array changes :

```
useEffect(() => {
  // code performed when stateVariable has changed
}, [stateVariable]);
```

In a class based component the solution would imply [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  if (this.state.stateVariable !== prevState.stateVariable) {
    // code performed when stateVariable has changed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try 
`this.setState({status: true},(this.state.status)=> console.log())`
In your case, console log was getting rendered before setState was completing its job.