# How to get the updated value of a state from a callback method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am building a React app and I have a code following this logic:

```
class ComponentTest extends Component {
  state = {test: 0}

  testingHandler = () => {
     console.log(this.state.test)
  }

  updateHandler = () => {
     let test = Math.random()  
     this.setState({test})
     this.testing()
  }
        
  render () {
     return (
        <button onClick={this.updateHandler}>Update</button>
     )
  }
}
```

What I need to do is get the  updated value of `test` in `testingHandler()`, however it doesn't happen, `testingHandler` just get the past value, it is like the state that is being received by `testingHandler` is always one step late.

For example, let's say that `test = 0`, then I click on the button that calls `updateHandler()` and now `test = 1`, after that `updateHandler()` calls `testingHandler()`, which I expect to get the new value of `test` which now is `1`, however I get the old value `0`. If I call `updateHandler()` again and update `test` to `2` I'll get `1` in `testingHandler()`, which is the past value.

How can I get this value updated from `testingHandler`?

I did everything that I could imagine, but I couldn't get this done. I believe it has something to do with the render logic of `React`, but I don't know exactly how this is working.

P.S. Passing the value as an argument is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setState is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

You can pass a callback function as the second argument of `setState` that will run right after the state has updated.  So in you case, you could do this:

```js
  updateHandler = () => {
     let test = Math.random()  
     this.setState( {test}, this.testingHandler )
  }
```

Comment: `this.testingHandler()` should be `this.testingHandler` for this to work. (Or `() => this.testingHandler()` if you really prefer)

Comment: yes thank you @RobinZigmond, I edited the answer - Berg, did that solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, but in a mix of your answer and the @RobinZigmond 's comment

Comment: Thank you very much you both

Answer (score 1):

copied from react documentation link: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState. Pass an updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values based on the current state

better you can pass it as a callback function or you can also pass the value to the function.

This link is also helpful: [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work. What you mean by that `you can also pass the value to the function`?

Comment: you can pass as parameter to the function this.testingHandler(test).

Answer (score 1):

```
  class ComponentTest extends Component {
    state = { test: 0 };

    testingHandler = () => {
      console.log(this.state.test);
    };

    updateHandler = () => {
      let test = Math.random();
      this.setState({ test }, () => this.testingHandler()); // pass it as a callback
     
    };

    render() {
      return <button onClick={this.updateHandler}>Update</button>;
    }
  }
```