# Why do I have to click twice for an event to fire in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling

Sorry for the simplicity of this question, I am pretty new to React. I built a calculator with two input fields and then buttons to handle the different calculations.  Now, I am transforming it into a more fully functional calculator with a whole keypad. In my code below, I am pretty sure that the way I have the "onClick" function written is the problem, but I am not sure how it is supposed to be written. (most of the code in the sample has to do with the initial project, and is not relevant to this question, I just wanted to include the whole component for good measure.)

When I click on the "1" button, it console logs 1 the first time, but the 1 at the top of the page doesn't show up until the second click.  What do I have going on here that isn't allowing the one to display at the top until I click the "1" button the second time?

First Click:
[App after first click on 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viJ41.png)

Second Click:
[App after second click on 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p6PE.png)

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setNum1 = this.setNum1.bind(this);
    this.setNum2 = this.setNum2.bind(this);
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    this.subtract = this.subtract.bind(this);
    this.multiply = this.multiply.bind(this);
    this.divide = this.divide.bind(this);
    this.clear = this.clear.bind(this);
    this.buttonPressed = this.buttonPressed.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      pressed: "",
      result: "",
      num1: "",
      num2: "",
    };
  }

  buttonPressed(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const pressed = e.target.name;
    const result = this.state.pressed;
    this.setState({ pressed });
    this.setState({ result });
    console.log(e.target.name);
  }

  setNum1(e) {
    const num1 = e.target.value ? parseInt(e.target.value) : "";
    this.setState({ num1 });
  }

  setNum2(e) {
    const num2 = e.target.value ? parseInt(e.target.value) : "";
    this.setState({ num2 });
  }

  add(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = this.state.num1 + this.state.num2;
    this.setState({ result });
  }

  subtract(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = this.state.num1 - this.state.num2;
    this.setState({ result });
  }

  multiply(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = this.state.num1 * this.state.num2;
    this.setState({ result });
  }

  divide(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = this.state.num1 / this.state.num2;
    this.setState({ result });
  }

  clear(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ num1: "", num2: "", result: 0 });
  }

  render() {
    const { num1, num2, result } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.result}</h1>
        <input onChange={this.setNum1} value={num1}></input>
        <input onChange={this.setNum2} value={num2}></input>
        <br />
        <button name="1" onClick={this.buttonPressed}>
          1
        </button>
        <button onClick={this.add}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.subtract}>-</button>
        <button onClick={this.multiply}>x</button>
        <button onClick={this.divide}>/</button>
        <button onClick={this.clear}>clear</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Calculator;
```

If anyone could help me learn what I need to do to fix this type of situation I would be so grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in

```
 buttonPressed(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // here e.target.name is 1 so value in const pressed becomes 1
    const pressed = e.target.name;
    // currently this.state.pressed is "" so result becomes "" if you want to show
    // first number as result use const result = e.target.name
    const result = this.state.pressed;
    this.setState({ pressed });
    this.setState({ result });
    console.log(e.target.name);
  }
```

You are setting your result to this.state.pressed which is empty during the first time so it sets result as empty string but during second time as this.state.pressed is 1 so it sets result as 1 hence its shown on second click

Comment: is this a solution ?

Comment: @Shaurya Oh I see that makes total sense now! Thank you so much.

Comment: @BARNOWL yes it is!

Answer (score 6):

**Reasoning:**

- Block that's causing issue

  ```
  buttonPressed(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const pressed = e.target.name;
    const result = this.state.pressed;
    this.setState({ pressed });
    this.setState({ result });
    console.log(e.target.name);
  }
  ```
- Reason: setState is going to take a while to update the state object values (i.e.) setState does not update state object immediately as its async in nature.
- reference: [Why React setState/useState does not update immediately - blog](https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately)

**Possible solution cases for this issue are listed below**

**Case A: setting 'result' state object based on 'pressed' state object**

- Note: setting state of other object once target object state change was set using call back function
- Objective: set 'result' state object only after 'pressed' state object was set
- Implementation: Once 'pressed' state was set, we execute a call back function to set 'result' state object
- Syntax:

  this.setState(setTargetStateObject, function() {
  // execute actions that has to be done after setTargetStateObject becomes completed
  });
- Solution:

  ```
   buttonPressed(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     const pressed = e.target.name;
     this.setState({ pressed }, function() {
       this.setState({ result: this.state.pressed });
     });
   }
  ```

**Case B: setting result state object  based on passed 'e' arg value**

- Solution:

  ```
  buttonPressed(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const pressed = e.target.name;
    // const result = this.state.pressed;

    // directly assign the 'e' arg value to the result const variable
    const result = pressed;

    // 'result' state object is not dependent on 'pressed' state object
    this.setState({ pressed });
    this.setState({ result });
    console.log(e.target.name);
  }
  ```

**Note:** I would suggest you to use **Functional component** as you can have a clean code with less number of lines, use newly introduced hooks by React team, easier to write tests and most importantly for the performance too.

**Created this sandbox for you** [calculator pgm - class vs functional react component](https://codesandbox.io/s/calculator-pgm-class-vs-functional-react-component-4gs8p) - you can view how the same program of yours be implemented in class vs functional components.

**References:**

- [Functional vs Class Components](https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108)
- [why setState not updating immediately - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)
- [Why React setState/useState does not update immediately - blog](https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately)