# React js - API response in this.state is empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to javascript and Reactjs and I am trying to fetch data from an api and then set an variable in my state to that data. When I console.log the response after I convert it to JSON, it works fine. However, after I set the data in this.state to the response and try to console.log(this.state.data) in my state, it shows an empty object in the console.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {data: {}}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query?symbol=TSLA&function=GLOBAL_QUOTE", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "230d86db60msheb2e40d44790598p1915e2jsn5074c9944675"
        }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({data: response})
      })
    
    console.log(this.state.data)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <h1></h1>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Fetch operation is async, that's why the second console log is empty, it has nothing to do with state or react.

Comment: State values are not updated immediately.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately

Comment: please remove your API key, seems like it's still active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `console.log(this.state.data)` gets called immediately in the `callstack` after the `fetch` function gets called ,so it gets the current value of data which is empty js object (which you initialized in your constructor)

```
 componentDidMount(){
    fetch("https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query?symbol=TSLA&function=GLOBAL_QUOTE", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": "230d86db60msheb2e40d44790598p1915e2jsn5074c9944675"
        }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.setState({data: response});

      })
    
    console.log(this.state.data) // this gets called immediately after fetch and so it contains the empty data object
  }
```

Instead try moving this `console.log` inside the fetch

```
 componentDidMount(){
        fetch("https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query?symbol=TSLA&function=GLOBAL_QUOTE", {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
              "x-rapidapi-host": "alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com",
              "x-rapidapi-key": "230d86db60msheb2e40d44790598p1915e2jsn5074c9944675"
            }
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({data: response});
          console.log(this.state.data). // now it will print the data which you set in the state
   
          })
        
       
      }
```

Comment: please remove your API key, seems like it's still active

Answer (score 2):

You are console logging after an asynchronous callback. Meaning the `console.log(this.state.data)` is called, when the data hasn't been changed, yet.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are changing state inside asynchronous call, and line

`this.setState({data: response});`

executes unpredictably *after* the line

`console.log(this.state.data)`,

Secondly, as [said](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) in React documentation,

> State Updates May Be Asynchronous. React may batch multiple
> `setState()` calls into a single update for performance.

Therefore, by calling `setState` you are scheduling state update, not updating it immediately.