# on Change is not capturing the last character of editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to get updated string from editor, but not getting last character from editor. I tried on blur, onchange also but not getting.

[image: output]

```
import React from 'react';import 'jodit';import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";import "../src/JoditEditors.css"class JoditEditors extends React.Component {constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
     
    test: 'content',

};}componentDidUpdate() {
}componentDidMount() {}updateContent = (value) => {
   this.setState({ test: value })
console.log(this.state.test);}newsetContent = (dds) => {
console.log(dds);}shoot() {
this.updateContent();
console.log(this.state.test);}jodit;setRef = jodit => this.jodit = jodit;config = {readonly: false}render() {
return (
    <div>
    <JoditEditor
        editorRef={this.setRef}
            value={this.state.test}
            config={this.config}
            //onBlur={newContent => this.newsetContent(newContent)} 
           // onBlur={() => this.newsetContent(this.state.test)}
            onChange={this.updateContent}
    />
        <button onClick={() => { this.shoot() }} >Take the shot!</button>
        </div>
);    }}export default JoditEditors;
```

Comment: If you're using React 16 or later, you want `onChange={evt => this.updateContent(evt)}` at the very least, because `this` is _not_ preserved automatically (unlike in React 15 and earlier), just like you're already doing for `onBlur`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i tried onChange={evt => this.updateContent(evt)} this one also but not working. Again last character is missing in onchange  & button click also

Comment: It won't fix this specific problem, but you _do_ need to fix that. Did you remember to check https://github.com/jodit/jodit-react, and if their docs didn't address this, did you file an issue for them to be aware of the fact that their project might have a bug?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah i tried all ways, then only i raised a request in this stack overflow for help

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how can i fix this issue

Comment: Are you using those `console.log` calls as evidence for this issue? Or is there something else that indicates the issue as well?

Comment: @HenryWoody yes, console log is my evidence, i attached that screenshot also. plz see once and help on this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Comment: @HenryWoody i tried above link also, but not working

Comment: The point is not to do anything differently but to recognize that state updates are not reflected immediately, so when you log your variable right after calling `setState`, the changes will not be shown. If you use the variable in another method, it should be updated correctly (for example add a button that just logs `state.test` when clicked, and you should see it).

Comment: @HenryWoody i already added button also, for testing purpose also, when i click on button i am NOT getting last character & onchange is not firing also. please see above button click code also

Comment: Can you please accept answer id you found it helpfull?

Answer (score 1):

you console it before the next render so the state isn't really updated yet...
this will indicate the real state:

```
updateContent = (value) => {
    this.setState({ test: value },()=>{
        console.log(this.state.test);
    })
}
```

Comment: can u be more specific?

Comment: tried above type of set-state function but comes to console its not updating last character. Whatever text comes in Value same text details displaying. Last character is not updating in Value itself

Comment: it seems like the problem then comes from inside the `JoditEditor`
can you make a code sandbox?

Comment: Please use this link: Enter some dummy text & see the console parallelly, Thank you for help https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b8pww5?file=src%2FExample.js

Comment: Note that this isn't actually an answer, though. If the original code worked fine and the issue is that _only_ console.log is used, instead of _actually rendering based on the onChange value_, then that should be a comment to the question.