# State outside of ComponentDidMount does not appear to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello when I console log the state of my component anywhere outside the componentDidMount method I get that my state is full of empty arrays when they should have been built. I am grabbing the data from a JSON file and inside the componentDidMount I can see that the state changes to arrays with data, however anywhere else such as in my render, the state is back to its initial state.

I imagine this problem has to do with the component's lifecycle so would love to understand what is going on.

Many thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import * as metrics from './metrics.json';

class MetricsTable extends React.Component {
    state = {
        coverages: [],
        speeds: [],
        qualities: [],
        responsiveness: [],
        securities: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        metrics[0].map((metric) => {
            
            if (metric.level_1 === 'Coverage') {
                let joined = this.state.coverages.splice(0, 0, metric)
                this.setState({ coverages: [...joined] })
            }

            if (metric.level_1 === 'Speed') {
                let joined = this.state.speeds.splice(0, 0, metric)
                this.setState({ speeds: [...joined] })
            }

            if (metric.level_1 === 'Quality') {
                let joined = this.state.qualities.splice(0, 0, metric)
                this.setState({ qualities: [...joined] })
            }

            if (metric.level_1 === 'Responsiveness') {
                let joined = this.state.responsiveness.splice(0, 0, metric)
                this.setState({ responsiveness: [...joined] })
            }
            
            if (metric.level_1 === 'Security') {
                let joined = this.state.securities.splice(0, 0, metric)
                this.setState({ securities: [...joined] })
            }
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        // when I console log on this line I get empty arrays for my state
        return (
            <div>
                // this following line displays my state with empty arrays
                <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre>
                hello
            </div>
        );
        
    }
    
}

export default MetricsTable;
```

The fist picture shows state that has arrays with data, this one is console logged inside componentDidMount.

The second picture is the console log of this.state in my render function
[image]

[image: this is the console log in my render function]

Comment: It depends on where exactly you log the state, and given that `this.setState` is async, you're probably doing it too early. Just add this to your JSX: `<pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre>` and you will see the state change just fine (also don't use `map` instead of `forEach`) see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately

Comment: Can you show or explain where exactly you are console logging?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response, I was console logging just outside of the map inside the componentDidMount, and that one displayed the arrays fully built.

Then I console logged inside the render (just above the return statement) and the arrays where empty

Comment: I have included the line in my jsx and it still shows as an empty array

Comment: What is displayed when you console log inside the render function?

Comment: Could you update the post with the way you included the line in the JSX? To check what's happening.

Comment: Also. is ever on of your if statement true?

Comment: Hi Nicholas, so the if statements do work, I know they do because when I console log in the componentDidMount I can see that the arrays were built and the state was set.

Comment: I have updated the post with images and comments

Comment: How about if we update the state once not for every if condition. Lets initialize variables before the mapping and update them in if condition and then after the map complete, update your state. Let's see if that sort your issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to this kind of code:

```js
let joined = this.state.coverages.splice(0, 0, metric)
```

Note that `joined` will be always an empty array. The `splice` method doesn't return a new result array.

You can update the code like this:

```js
let joined = [...this.state.coverages, metric];
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the above code with a hook.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let metrics = [
  [
    [
      {
        level_1: "Coverage",
        name: "Coverage_1"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        level_1: "Speed",
        name: "Speed_1"
      }
    ]
  ]
];
const MetricsTable = () => {
  const [coverages, setcoverages] = useState([]);
  const [speeds, setspeeds] = useState([]);
  const [qualities, setqualities] = useState([]);
  const [responsiveness, setresponsiveness] = useState([]);
  const [securities, setsecurities] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    metrics[0].map((metric) => {
      console.log("metric = ", metric);
      if (metric[0].level_1 === "Coverage") {
        setcoverages(coverages.concat(metric));
      }

      if (metric[0].level_1 === "Speed") {
        setspeeds(speeds.concat(metric));
      }

      if (metric[0].level_1 === "Quality") {
        setqualities(qualities.concat(metric));
      }

      if (metric[0].level_1 === "Responsiveness") {
        setresponsiveness(responsiveness.concat(metric));
      }

      if (metric[0].level_1 === "Security") {
        setsecurities(securities.concat(metric));
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      coverages:{coverages.length}
      <br />
      speeds:{speeds.length}
      <br />
      qualities:{qualities.length}
      <br />
      responsiveness:{responsiveness.length}
      <br />
      securities :{securities.length}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MetricsTable;
```

i am consider metrics was [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-kirch-o5850?file=/src/MetricsTable.js)

why remove joined?
for example

```
var fruits = [];

var t= fruits.splice(0, 0, [{name:"Kiwi",id:"1"}]);
 console.log("t = ",t)
```

`t` is empty.and `fruits` not empty and contain data.

Comment: I had wrote it in with hooks at first. Thanks for this but the state still displays an empty array when I console log after the useEffect method

Comment: Can I have a sample of the data ```metrics.json```?

Comment: Is the metric in map an object or an array?

Comment: metric is an object

Comment: Can I have a sample of the data ```metrics.json```?