# How to use "setState" in react, and why it does not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know why it returns a log `<empty string>` when I already assigned a value using `setState`. Does the `setState` not working? Please help me to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
const App = (params) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState('');

    const getDatas = async (params) => {
        const { data } = await http().get('todo');
        
        setData('new data');
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getDatas();
        console.log(data);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="border">Display text</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Also related (besides the duplicate link): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately

Comment: Well, underlying issue is same as the duplicate, but you complicate with `getDatas` being an async function, so `data` is still the current state when logged. The http GET will resolve during *some* future render cycle.