# Reactjs dropdown setState being set on second value change

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, setstate

In the following component, the handleDropdownChange function does not set the state for "data" on the first change, it only sets it after the second change. For example, when I select 'Electronics', nothing happens. I then select 'Produce', and the page loads all 'Electronics' products.

```
export default class ProductList extends Component {
        
    constructor(props){             
        super(props);       
        this.handleDropdownChange= this.handleDropdownChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {      
             data: fulldata
            };      
    }


    handleDropdownChange(e){
        
        e.preventDefault();
        var filtered_data = fulldata.filter(prod => prod.category == e.target.value);       
        this.setState({ data:filtered_data })
        
    }
    

   render(){

    return(
               <div>Category</div>
                        <select id="filter-cat" onChange={this.handleDropdownChange}>
                            <option value="Apparel">Apparel</option>    
                            <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
                            <option value="Produce">Produce</option>
                        </select>

              {this.state.data}
     );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me was found here:

[setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately/41278440)

My updated method looks like this:

```
async handleDropdownChange(e){
        
        e.preventDefault();
        var filtered_data = fulldata.filter(prod => prod.category == e.target.value);       
        await this.setState({ data:filtered_data })
        
    }
```

This feels hacky and I wish there was a better way, but for now this is only solution that works me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay, although I'm not entirely sure how you're rendering `this.state.data` because by the looks of it it is an array. You can modify your `handleDropdownChange` to store the selected item instead.

Your state:

```
    this.state = {
      data: fulldata[0]
    };
```

Your `onChange` handler:

```
handleDropdownChange(e) {
  const filtered_data = fulldata.find(
    (prod) => prod.category === e.target.value
  );
  this.setState({ data: filtered_data });
}
```

Here's the working [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-gates-ki7dt?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Your code does work in the sandbox but it does not work in my code. I found a solution that I have provided as an answer.