# setState() not changing the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been struggling with this from yesterday, and couldn't solve it.

Basically, we are making a website for a restaurant, which customer can use to order foods and pay for it.
The feature I'm implementing now is, when user press the checkout button, it goes to ***/order_confirm*** and display all the menus ordered. I'm trying to pass the order number by setting the url as ***/order_confirm/id*** where id is the order number. Everything works fine, except that when I do setState() to change the value of the ordId which is state and pass the state value to the according class, it seems like setstate not changing the value at all.

```
handleCheckoutRequest = async () => {
const { tableNumber } = this.state;
const orderOrdered = 1;
const menuItemIds = this.props.menuItems.map((a) => a.id);
const menuItemCounts = this.props.menuItems.map((a) => a.count);

await API.post(`/orders/`, null, {
      params: { tableNumber, orderStatus: orderOrdered },
    })
      .then(async (response) => {
        const orderId = response.data.id; // this works

    await API.post(`/ordered_items/${orderId}`, null, {
      params: { menuItemIds, menuItemCounts },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            responses: ["Successfully added order items"], // this works
            responseStatus: "success", // this works as well
            ordId: orderId, // this doesn't
        });
        console.log(orderId); // display 25 on the console (which is right)
        console.log(this.state.ordId); // display -1 which is the default value
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  })
};
```

I get this error in console.

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
> a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
> componentWillUnmount method.

I've tried setting the tempo, using the arrow function in the setState(), declaring method outside and using the method to change the value. It all didn't work.

---

This is handleCheckout method.

```
handleCheckout = () => {
  const { menuItems } = this.props;
  const { tableNumber } = this.state;
  let responses = [];
  if (tableNumber === -1 || !tableNumber)
    responses.push("No table has been selected");
  if (menuItems.length < 1)
    responses.push("No menu items have been added to cart");
  if (responses.length > 0) {
    this.setState({ responses, responseStatus: "fail" });
    return;
  }
  this.setState({ responses: [], responseStatus: "" });

  this.handleCheckoutRequest();
};
```

this is the part where I'm passing the state as props.

```
<div className="cart__bottom">
   <Checkout
      id={this.state.ordId}
      onTableChange={this.handleTableChange}
      onCheckout={this.handleCheckout}
      responses={responses}
      responseStatus={responseStatus}
   />
</div>
```

This is render() of where it's passed

```
render() {
const { id, onTableChange, onCheckout, responses, responseStatus } = this.props;
return (
  <div className="cart__checkout">
    <Response responses={responses} responseStatus={responseStatus} />
    <input
      className="input mb-2"
      type="number"
      name="tableNumber"
      placeholder="Table Number"
      onChange={onTableChange}
    />
    <Link to={{
      pathname: "/order_confirm/" + id
    }}>
      <button
        className="button is-primary is-fullwidth"
        onClick={onCheckout}
      >
        Checkout
      </button>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

}

I also found an article that seems like it could be a solution to my problem. Only barrier is that I'm not good enough with React to apply the solutions.

[Avoid React state update warnings on unmounted components](https://medium.com/@shanplourde/avoid-react-state-update-warnings-on-unmounted-components-bcecf054e953)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Comment: A tip is to try to avoid nesting promises. You are also using async await and then you are not using it. Try to stick to one of them.

Comment: Try to separate the api request logic from the UI logic. I think a "repository pattern" could solve your problem.

Comment: @Sysix Tried top 3 answers, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: where do you use the state? maybe u need `useEffect`

Comment: I'm using state because the only way I can get the order number is when API.post is returning, I need to pass the order number to a component as props but I don't have access to the response.data.id outside this post function...

Comment: Please share the rest of the related code of your app, such as the react component where you are executing that call, and the hooks/lifecycle methods, the error you are getting seems to be related to that part

Comment: I've updated the question. Please have a look, thanks.

Comment: When an API call is made, is it in onCheckout/handleCheckout method?

Comment: @G07cha I've updated so that it shows which method it is in. It's in handleCheckoutRequest().

Comment: This doesn't quite give insight into the chain of execution, is it being called when the Checkout button is pressed? Because the button has a onClick handler with a different name.

Comment: Added handleCheckout method! Should've added it the first time

Answer (score 0):

Try not to mix async await with normal promise. Stick to one of them.
Also try not to nest promises since that will give you callback hell.

```
const postOrder = async () => {
  const apiPostOrdersResponse = await API.post(`/orders/`, null, {
    params: { tableNumber, orderStatus: orderOrdered },
  });

  const orderId = apiPostResponse.data.id;

  const apiPostOrderItemResponse = await API.post(
    `/ordered_items/${orderId}`,
    null,
    {
      params: { menuItemIds, menuItemCounts },
    }
  );

  this.setState({
    responses: ['Successfully added order items'],
    responseStatus: 'success',
    ordId: orderId,
  });
};
```

Comment: what happens if you console.log the `orderId`

Comment: I did console.log(orderId) just under the const orderId line, but console displays nothing. Tried 3 times, still get the same result.