# first response from the api call is returning null/undefined but in the second time i am getting the correct response in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, use-effect

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';   
function App() {
    const  [memes,setMemes] = useState({});
    useEffect( ()=> {
    const fetchMemes  =     async () => { 
    await  axios.get("")
   .then (response => {
    setMemes({memes:   response.data.data.memes[(Math.floor(Math.random()*10))]})
     console.log(memes)
       })
     .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      })
  
      }

     fetchMemes()
  },[]) }
```

while fetching the api i am getting null response first response returns null response and after the second run or render it return the response
:
[responses returned from the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOyiX.jpg)

with getting this empty array in the first response I cannot perform array.map() as it is a null array
please help solving this issue i've  been trying many ways but none worked ☹

Comment: you're not logging the response, you're logging `memes`, which is `{}` on first render and hasn't yet been updated when the first `console.log` runs. If you want to see teh response, just `console.log(response)` instead. (Or step through your code, or just check the response directly in the Network tab.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Thanks @Robin Zigmond  , it tried your solution but that doesn't seems to work out , the api response that response i am trying to `setState` , by setting the state i want to perform .`map()` operation and if it returns null or undefined that sadly cannot be done