# how to use state in same useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-effect

After setting the state of a variable in useEffect, I console.log it on the next line which gives
`undefined`

Why is this so and how do i use the state variable?

```
const [item, setItem] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      const doFunction = async () => {
        try{
          setItem("hi")
          console.log(item)
      },[item]);
    doFunction()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Comment: Welcome to SO! `setState` is asynchronous, so your `console.log` below the `setState` will execute first. `setState` just _registers_ a value for React to use in the next re-render and isn't anything like a synchronous assignment. Please see the canonical dupe.

Comment: Your effect will run into an infinite loop. You're setting `item` in the effect, and you're asking for the effect to get executed whenever `item` changes (the `[item]` array you're passing in). In your effects where you're setting a state, you don't try to also fetch the same state (and you don't need to, since you already have the value).

Comment: If you setState inside an effect of the same state it will result in infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With hooks it's rather impossible because setState is asynchronus function which means that state of items can't be set immeditiely. You can create another useEffect to handle when state changed.

```js
useEffect( () => {
    setItems( "hi" )
}, [] ) // empty array means "when component mounted"

useEffect( () => {
    if ( items ) {
         /* do something here */
    }
}, [items] ) // array with items means "when itemas state change"
```

If you realy want to use value which you passing to setState in same hook you can store it for a while in normal variable.

```js
useEffect( () => {
    const temp = "hi"
    setItems(  temp )

    console.log( items ) // undefined
    console.log( temp ) // "hi"
}, [] ) // empty array means "when component mounted"
```