# React State fields missing inside OnChange

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to validate a form in React. Every time input is changed in the field, I try to validate it:

```
// Consutructor
this.state{
  Form_errors:
     Key1: false,
     Key2: false
}
handleChange(e, name){
                
    this.setState({
        [name]: e.target.valueAsNumber
    });
                
    // validate fields
    this.validate_field(e, name);
}
```

Then on form submit, I check every field is true:

```
handle_submit(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
                
    // validate form immediately                
    this.validate_form();
}

validate_form(){        
    // check all fields are true
    for (var field in this.state.form_errors) {
        if(!this.state.form_errors[field]){
            this.setState({
                validated: false
            });                     
            return false;
        }
    }
                
    this.setState({
        validated: true
    });
}
```

At this stage, `validate_form()` only sees the recent field that was updated in `handleChange`, so returns true after 1 iteration. If I `console.log` the current state, only the current key value exists and not the others.

I also have conditional class in `render()` that also sees only a single field at a time.

Why are the rest of the fields missing in `state`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question would be clearer if you wouldn't mind editing your post to show your render function and state. What's going on with `this.state.form_errors` -- where is that set? Zooming back and explaining what you're trying to achieve at a high level might be useful as well because there could be a fundamentally more elegant way to go about doing it than your attempt. Thanks.

Comment: this.state.form_errors is set at the constructor. Very simply: this.state{form_errors: {key1: false, key2:false}}     The render doesnt make a difference, why is console.log(this.state) missing form_error.key2?

Comment: Where's `console.log(this.state)` in the code? State updates are asynchronous, so if you're doing `this.setState({foo: "bar"}); console.log(this.state)` you won't see `foo: "bar"`. See [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately). Please edit your question rather than adding code in the comments. To get an answer to your question, the behavior has to be reproducible, preferably with a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538). See [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen, console log is just an example, the loop in validate_form runs for a single iteration. I added the state in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state was being reset when only a single property was updated.

```
this.setState({
  [property]: newVal
});
```

It means that `this.state.property2` would be 'forgotten'.
Doing:

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  [property]: newVal
});
```