# Two times click is necessary to Login in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, authentication, try-catch

I am trying to make a Login page and I am successful in some way. So here is my Login component:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import useForm from "../components/LoginForm/useForm";
import validate from "components/LoginForm/validate";
import redtruck from "../assets/img/red-truck.png";
import auth from "../Authentication/auth";

import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const Login = ({ submitForm, history }) => {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

  async function submitForm() {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    try {
      await fetchLogin(values.email, values.password);
      if(login){
        auth.login(() => {
          history.push("/admin");
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      auth.login(() => {
        history.push("/");
      })
    }
  }

  const { handleChange, values, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm(
    submitForm,
    validate
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user-info")) {
      submitForm();
    }
  }, []);
  const fetchLogin = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await Axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: `url`,
        headers: {
        },
        data: {
          user_email: email,
          user_password: password,
        },
      });
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setLogin(true);
        localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(res.data));
      }
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className="form-container">
          <div className="form-content-left">
            <img className="form-img" src={redtruck} alt="spaceship" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-content-right">
            <h1>SIGN IN</h1>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form-inputs">
                <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
                  Email address
                </label>
                <input
                  id="signin-email"
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  className="form-input"
                  value={values.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                {errors.email && <p>{errors.email}</p>}
              </div>
              <div className="form-inputs">
                <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">
                  Password
                </label>
                <input
                  id="signin-password"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  className="form-input"
                  value={values.password}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                {errors.password && <p>{errors.password}</p>}
                {login ? "" : <p>The password or the email is wrong</p>}
              </div>
              <button
                variant="primary"
                type="submit"
                className="form-input-btn"
              >
                LOGIN
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Login);
```

So the *login* state is set to true when email and password are right for the user. Later I want to use it when redirecting page to "/admin". But my problem is I have to click twice to login in the first place. Besides I am not sure, if the catch part is right:

```
catch (e) {
      auth.login(() => {
        history.push("/");
      })
    }
```

So I would be really glad, if you can give me some hint about it.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

it is not that you have to press twice, you can check component state, sometimes React batches setState and then update value. You can look at this [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)