# Why is setState not updating my state value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
function LoginComponent(){
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
  
  function handleClick(){
    console.log('before', clicked)
    setClicked(true)
    console.log('after', clicked)
  }
  return(
    <a onClick={handleClick}>
      random text
      </a>
  )
}
```

When I run this, the console outputs before false after false. Why is this? I have no clue why this behavior is like this.

Comment: State is updated asynchronously and it is constant within a particular render of a component. Component can't see the updated state until it re-renders. You can use the `useEffect` hook to see the updated state: `useEffect(() => { console.log(clicked) }, [clicked])`

Comment: `clicked` is assigned in the line `const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)` **only**. Calling `setState` will update the internal state, resulting in the _next_ call to `useState` to return the new value, but it cannot automagically change your local variable `clicked` too. (You could instead write something like `setClicked(clicked = true)` and change `const` to `let` so that `clicked` is changeable.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setState doesn't update the state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

Because setting state is an asynchronous action.
It takes some time to update.
[Check react documentation link to know more](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do)

You can check the updated value by

```
    useEffect(()=> { 
         console.log("clicked", clicked);
 },[clicked]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of reasons for this behavior:

- State is updated asynchronously
- In any particular render, state and props don't change, changes are only reflected when component re-renders

If you want to log the updated value of `clicked`, put the log statement in the `useEffect` hook.

You can't update and log the updated value of any state variable in the same render. Component will have to re-render to reflect changes due to state update.

Similarly, if you want to call a function with the updated value of `clicked`, call the function from inside the `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 1):

`setClicked` is asynchronous. You must check the state updated in `useEffect`

```
function LoginComponent(){
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
  
  function handleClick(){
    setClicked(true)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(clicked);
  },[clicked])

  return(
    <a onClick={handleClick}>
      random text
      </a>
  )
}
```