# How to redirect after or during the onClick function of Button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redirect, next.js

I am trying to add a feature in my Next.js website that allows users to click a button to create a new group, then redirect them to an "Invite members" page that uses the auto generated group_id in the URL with dynamic routing. I am currently using Next.js's Router, but I feel like there is a better (or working) way to do this.
JS (within `export default function groups ()`):

```
const [num, setNum] = useState("");
const router = useRouter()
const createGroup = async () => {
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("chatgroups")
    .insert([
      {
        group_name: groupName,
        creator: user.email,
        description: groupDesc,
        accepted_members: user.email + " ",
        invited_members: ""
      }
    ]);

  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    setNum("/groups/" + String(data[0].group_id));
    
    router.push(num);
  }
};
```

HTML (returned in same JS script):

```
<button type="button" className="bg-yellow-500 rounded px-12 py-2" onClick={()=> {
  createGroup()
  }} >Insert test group</button>
```

I have tried using the Router for both server and client and both did not recognize .push()

```
import { Router } from "next/dist/client/router";
import { Router } from "next/dist/server/router"; //neither of these recognized the method.
```

My goal is to execute the function createGroup(), in which the value of "data" will receive the auto-generated int id of the new SQL row. Then I want to use this id to redirect to "/groups/[id]", where [id] is the new ID. I tried using a Link with the `const [num, setNum]`, but it performs the redirect BEFORE the new value is set. I am relatively new to Next.js, so I would appreciate any help with this.

Desired output:
Click button -> adds row to SQL table with group_id = 17.
Redirect user to "/groups/invite_members/17".

Edit: I have updated my main JS code above to use useRouter(), now it only works every second click.

Comment: Setting state is an async operation, the `num` you use in the `router.push` call will not have the value you set in `setNum(...)` the first time you click on the button. Try setting the value to a variable and use that in the `router.push` call, e.g. `const path = "/groups/" + String(data[0].group_id);` then set the state and call `router.push(path);`.

Comment: @juliomalves thank you, that solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that calling [`setNum` does not update `num` immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately), as setting state is an asynchronous operation.

This means that on the first button click `num` will still have its default value (`""`) when `router.push(num)` is called, and only when clicking the button a second time will the `num` state have updated with the value set previously.

To fix it, you can set the value to a variable and use that in the `router.push` call instead.

```js
const path = "/groups/" + String(data[0].group_id);

setNum(path);

router.push(path);
```